# an internal error occurred during: uploading code to lambda

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, aws-lambda

This exception is thrown while uploading code to lambda. I tried but no where found the solution.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1647)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.util.UploadFunctionUtil.performFunctionUpload(UploadFunctionUtil.java:95)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsJobWizard$1.run(AbstractAwsJobWizard.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException cannot be found by com.amazonaws.eclipse.javasdk_1.11.248
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure Eclipse is running with Java 8.  AWS Toolkit requires JAXB for the upload to AWS S3, but JAXB was deprecated in Java 9 & 10, and removed from Java 11.  If you're running Eclipse under Java 9, 10, or 11, Eclipse/AWS Toolkit won't find JAXB and you'll get this error.

You can resolve the problem by specifying the JVM Eclipse should use on startup.  Instructions for various platforms found here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: This bit me when using Eclipse J2EE 2019-06, because by default it uses Java 12.

Comment: Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) requires Java 11 or newer JRE/JDK. Older Eclipse versions must be used until [ws-toolkit-eclipse #217](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/issues/217) is resolved.

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api to your dependencies

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1</version> 
</dependency>
```